# Elasticsearch classification

Tags: elasticsearch, classification

I have data with 4 attributes, 
3 are temperature values (t1, t2, t3) and last one is alarm which says if the temperature values should raise alarm or not.

`T1   T2   T3   alarm`

`15   30   18   Y`

`12   32   19   Y`

`17   20   12   N`

`20   18   13   N`

I want to do following: learn elasticsearch (basically like neural net) the values (classification) in which elasticsearch watcher or job should raise alarm based on temperature values. I don't know if there is linear corellation between temperature attributes and alarm value, that's why i want to use machine learning. Is it possible to solve this use case just with elasticsearch, and if so, can you pls direct me to the right direction how to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail with an example.

Comment: edited with explanation